# MVC4 - Updating Model using Entity Framework - Null Exception passing httpPost paramater

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, nullreferenceexception

Am learning MVC and am trying to create a simple form which will allow the user to update the description of a model.

The problem is am getting a null exception

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'ThreatID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetThreat(Int32)' in
>   'RiskAssesmentApplication.Controllers.ThreatsController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

The Get method for the form seems to be working as expected, but the id  isn't being passed back into the HttpPost Method parameters and I cant work how am supposed to pass it in. I ran a search and seen something about using a `@hiddenfor` helper but it hasn't work for me.

Here are my methods

```
 public ActionResult GetThreat(int ThreatID)
        {
            // ViewModel.Threat = repository.GetThreat(ThreatID);
            RiskAssessmentApplicationEntities _DBContext = new RiskAssessmentApplicationEntities();
            ThreatWithSecurityEventAndISOControlViewModel ViewModel = new ThreatWithSecurityEventAndISOControlViewModel();
            ViewModel.Threat = _DBContext.Threats.Single(x => x.ID == ThreatID);
            ViewModel.SecurityEvents = _DBContext
                                        .ThreatHasSecurityEvents
                                        .Include("ThreatHasSecurityEvent.SecurityEvent")
                                        .Where(x => x.ThreatID == ThreatID)
                                        .Select(x => x.SecurityEvent);

            return View(ViewModel);                                   
        }

[HttpGet]
public ViewResult EditThreat(int ThreatID)
{
    Threat Threat = repository.Threats.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ThreatID);
    return View(Threat);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditThreat(Threat Threat)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.SaveThreat(Threat);
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} new description has been saved", Threat.Description);
        return RedirectToAction("GetThreat");
    }
    else
    {
        // something is incorrect!
        return View(Threat);
    }
}
```

Here's my view

```
@model RiskAssesmentApplication.Threat
@using RiskAssesmentApplication;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditThreat";
}
<div style="font-family: Calibri">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Threat Description</legend>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID);
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => @Model.Description, "Threat Description")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.Description)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.Description )
            </div> 
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
            </p>
        }
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And this is my Model

```
public class ThreatWithSecurityEventAndISOControlViewModel
    {
        public Threat Threat { get; set; }
        public SecurityEvent SecurityEvent { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ISOControl> ISOControls { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SecurityEvent> SecurityEvents { get; set; }
```

Am Really stumped on this so any help will be appreciated

Comment: The error message relates to a controller method `GetThreat()` but all you have shown is the `EditThreat()` methods

Comment: Assuming `GetThreat()` has parameter `int ThreatID`, then it needs to be something like `return RedirectToAction("GetThreat", new { ThreatID = Threat.ID });` - but you need to show your method and the model to be sure

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, this did the trick, I'll still post the GetThreat() method + model up for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetThreat()` method expect parameter `int ThreatID` (not nullable) but in your `EditThreat()` method, you do not pass a value when you redirect. Change

```
return RedirectToAction("GetThreat");
```

to

```
return RedirectToAction("GetThreat", new { ThreatID = Threat.ID });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to say for sure but it sounds like you are working with a disconnected entity. Just because you are using an entity model that has the ID of a row in your database doesn't mean it's connected to your data context. Use the model that is passed back in the post to look up the connected version. Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Whatever(Threat model)
{
    var connectedModel = context.Threats.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ID);
    connectedModel.SomeProperty = model.SomeProperty; //or use AutoMapper
    context.SaveChanges();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `RedirectToAction` by:

```
return RedirectToAction("EditThreat", new { ThreatID = 99 });
```